# How can I incorporate the path of a jump into my A* implementation?

Tags: movement, path-finding, jumping

I need to calculate the path of a jump via A* for a simple platformer game. Calculating the direction is simple, but translating the jump physics into pre-calcuted voxel paths is a bit difficult. Especially when you factor things in like obstacles. Based on the image below, what is the best way to calculate jump in A*?

To give better context, here is a video of the game I'm working on. Will be implemented here to get companions following the player

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMrbCtb2Buk

[image: Jump Example]

Comment: map each jump that is possible (either by hand or automatically) once and add those to the graph

Comment: Well I've gotten that far, but I'm trying to figure out the most bulletproof way to calculate the jump metrics in the algorithm's list processing. For example calculating the jump arc, how should this be accomplished?

Comment: you assign a cost to each jump that doesn't kill the jumper and then it's just another option at that node

Comment: Are you wishing to calculate the set of points the jumper will go through whilst jumping from one platform to another?

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between path finding and jumping physics? Are you writing code to decide if it's possible to jump from A to B? Or how long does it take to jump there?

Comment: Good question Arthur, trying to figure out the relationship between jumping physics and path. Not so much how long, more of is it possible (with the necessary trajectory).

Comment: Jordan Fisher (the guy behind Cloudberry Kingdom) had published a article on gamasutra about how to create a procedural plaformer, you might have a look there : http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/170049/How_to_Make_Insane_Procedural_Platformer_Levels_.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After heavily contemplating and consulting with many devs on how to solve this problem, I eventually came to the conclusion that A* on a pre-processed map is the best solution. Here's why:

- Practically instant run time since A* traverses the map with everything it needs to calculate the jumps
- Pre-processing can be performed at level load, fast enough to run again later after tile destruction
- Clearance support is extremely achievable
- Maps can be easily broken up into quadrants for extremely large tile amounts (1000 x 1000 voxels plus)

The process to use pre-processing with A* for gravity can be broken down into a few simple steps. If you already have A* this shouldn't take too long to implement.

1. Calculate clearance values from collision tiles
2. Discover all ledges by looking for missing tiles on the top, left, and/or right or a tile. Also get all walkable tiles
3. Connect all ledges within the maximum jumping distance and that pass a simulated parabola line test (or physics but this will probably kill your runtime)
4. Perform a runoff test on all ledges that draws a curved 135 degree angle in the direction of the ledge. Anywhere the test lands create another jump connection
5. Run a drop test to see if fall locations are present on the sides of ledges
6. A pre-existing A* implementation should be able to swallow this information with minimal tweaking since it can traverse through flat walkways and ledge connections now

Additionally here is an interactive demo I built based upon the above theory (source code available).

http://ashblue.github.io/pathfinding-platformer/

Answer (score 3):

First of all understand that A* only works well for a limited set of problems. If you can't make a heuristic that gets close enough to the actually required time then Dijkstra's algorithm is often faster. On top of that it works with teleporters, speed boosters and anything else that breaks the standard assumptions of Euclidean geometry. And it is easier to implement.

The theoretical perfect solution to the problem is to use a search space that include velocity, and any other variable that is relevant to movement, so for a typical 2D platformer you would have a 4D search space consisting of position and velocity. Whether or not this is computationally feasible depend very much on the nature of the game.

If you use float precision it is pretty much impossible to make perfect pathfinding in any case, but if your physics system binds all values to a limited integer space it may be perfectly doable.

If the complete search for any reason is too much you may want to artificially limit the search space, this could for instance be through any combination of the following:

- Do not allow slowing down while running. (Though you must provide some means for the character to turn around before and after jumps.)
- Do only allow jumping at specific points. (Edge of platform and X distance before the end of other reachable platforms seems suitable.)
- Limit the air control to only change simulated input every X physics frames.
- Implement "buggy A*", that is favour branches that are physically closer to the target even though you cannot guarantee that they will be faster if they are chosen.
- Converge paths that are almost at the same spot in search space, if two routes lead to running in the same direction on the same platform you should terminate the slowest of the two search branches.

Depending on the context the result of these implementations may be satisfactory.

This whole answer assumes a fixed physics rate, combining variable physics rate and predictive AI is a world of trouble.

Comment: dijkstra is A* with heuristic set to 0, the heuristic can just be euclid distance to goal

Comment: Only needs to fire once every couple seconds. Its for companions to follow the main character. Meaning there is some leeway to cut corners for reducing overhead. Thx you btw, this is a great writeup.

Comment: @ratchetfreak A* demands a minimum with the same unit as the optimization criteria, time in this case. You have to divide that distance by the maximum possible speed to get a valid heuristic. Though reading it again I do think my answer needs an adjustment.

Comment: I think the limiting factor will be memory space if you go in time steps of 1 frame

Comment: *"If you can't make a heuristic that gets close enough to the actually required time then Dijkstra's algorithm is often faster"* - This is incorrect, A\* with a consistent heuristic is always as fast or faster than Dijkstra's, even if that heuristic is horribly inaccurate.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Correction: It never searches more nodes. What you forget is that A* takes more time per node as it has to calculate the heuristic, check which path is fastest when a collision occurs, and not least keep a "scoreboard" of heuristic results. In the naive implementation you probably get a factor 5 to 10 slowdown for constantly updating a search tree. But if you realise that you can still get most of the benefits of A* with a lazy unordered approach you can probably get it down to around a factor 2.

Comment: Scoreboard? Search tree? Collisions? Can you give more details about what you mean by these, and how it's different from Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: @amitp With Dijkstra you simply extend every branch by 1 iteration in every search step, when two branches converge/collide it is safe to assume that the newest branch is not faster that the older branch, and you can without further calculations drop the newest branch. With A* you use the heuristic score to determine what branch to extend next, so you have to keep the branches ordered by score. Doing this perfectly requires a search tree, which has O(log(n)) insertion complexity. Dijkstra doesn't need a similar order and therefore has O(1) complexity for the equivalent operation.

Comment: @eBusiness: The term you're looking for is 'priority queue,' not search tree.  Both A\* and Dijkstra's require a priority queue, and both can *"assume the newest branch is not faster than the older branch"* if the heuristic is [consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic), so your statement is incorrect; both A\* and Dijkstra have the same speed-complexity.  The heuristic calculation is assumed to be trivial *(which in real-life it almost always is)*.

Comment: @eBusiness: with Dijkstra you have a variable cost, not 1 at every step, and you have to order the queue just like A\*. I think you're thinking of Breadth First Search.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Every part of the process is trivial if you have done it right. We can argue about exactly how great the cost of A* is, it is or course going to vary between tasks and implementations, but it is there, always. @ ampit In this case every step cost 1 physics cycle, and therefore you can keep them ordered simply by sending newly created branches to the back of the queue. In other cases you are right that it may be more complicated. Dijkstra by the way is a breadth-first algorithm.