# Calculate Jump Limits

Tags: physics, path-finding, jumping

My question is in a similar vein to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/69260/how-can-i-incorporate-the-path-of-a-jump-into-my-a-implementation), I am creating a pre-mapped pathfinding solution much akin to how Ash Blue was for my 2D platformer-style game (in XNA). As part of the process, I have to be able to 'neighbor' nodes in the pathfinding algorithm. To be able to do this, I need a procedural manner to precalculate the maximum capabilities of motion from a given game object at a given location. I am having a difficult time with one specific aspect of this: I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to test whether or not a game object will be able to successfully jump to a given platform from where they are standing. I know there's a way to express this in some manner of equation, but I cannot find what the proper equation would be, it's probably in the vein of projectile physics, but the answer eludes me. If anybody can shed some insight into the matter, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Do you mean that you are firing your objects at some maximum velocity and you want to know the maximum range they can go? If so I can write up an answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried to tackle this myself but got stuck, fortunately [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) came to the rescue with this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127300/maximum-range-of-a-projectile-launched-from-an-elevation).

**Summary**

Given a particle which starts at position `(0,0)` and is fired at velocity `v_max` the maximum range it can achieve is,

```
x_max = Sqrt(v_max^4 / g^2 - 2 * v_max^2 * y_fin / g)
```

where `g` is the acceleration due to gravity (for earth `g ~ 9.81`) and `y_fin` is the final height of the particle (e.g. the height of the platform it needs to reach. This maximum range is achieved when the particle is fired at an angle,

```
theta = Atan( (1 - 2 * y_fin * g / v_max^2)^(-1/2) )
      = Atan( Sqrt(1 / ((1 - 2 * y_fin * g / v_max^2)) ),
```

where `Atan` is the inverse `tan` function.

**Note**

If desired I can explain in more detail how to achieve this result (as after seeing the approach in the linked question I was able to solve it myself) it requires knowledge of differentiation and trigonometric identities but is not too difficult.

Comment: I don't think I understand, if y_fin is the desired final height of the particle, wouldn't that potentially result in an x_max that is higher than the particle is capable of achieving? Or is that essentially how you test if the particle is capable of reaching the target?

Comment: Because platforms can be lower than where the particle starts the particle can go further than if the platform is at the same height. So if `y_fin` is very large and negative then the particle will go further. Of however all platforms are at the same height then it simplifies. I can post an update including that tomorrow.